# Use Jitsi for my own web app

Tags: java, web, webrtc, rtp, jitsi

I want to send real time video streaming to my web page I am making, I make a C and C++ app that use udp, rtp, but I don't have a good perfomance it is so slow, then I try jitsi and it is very wonderfull, I wanted to try jitsy libraries but I can't use the examples, AVReceive2.java and AVTransmit2.java, the AVTransmit2 starts, it say  "Found Sony Visual Communication" and then I have a "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: device
And then nothing happened.
I don't know if someone can help me, what is the way that I have to do it?, but the goal is that, i want to send real time video to my web Page, the camera is on a debian GNU/linux without user interface, and my server is on centos 7 X64 without user interface too.

Comment: Why don t you use the two existing C++ stacks: Webrtc.org or openWebRTC.org

Comment: I think you could use this Janus gateway which is written in c https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/

Comment: You are amazing, it work very good, I am trying... https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ and the examples  in https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment